# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: routeCollection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model

I am trying to dynamically create a url inside a model in my application but having some issues getting it to work.
This is what I do

```
UrlHelper url = new UrlHelper(); var link = "<a href="+@url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName", new { controller = "ControllerName", action = "ActionName", id = UrlParameter.Optional },"http")+">Link</a>";
```

but when I try to run it I get the following error:

**Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: routeCollection**

Please, I will appreciate any help to resolve this.

I am working on MVC 5, ASP.Net 4.5, Entity Framework 6

Comment: You cant unless you were to pass the current `RequestContext` to the model and even then it would make no sense to do this. Create the link in the view using `@Html.ActionLink()`

Answer (score -1):

If you inject urlHelper to your view model, you can access it then to create links:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new ViewModel(this.Url);
        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View();
    }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    private readonly UrlHelper _urlHelper;

    public ViewModel(UrlHelper urlHelper)
    {
        _urlHelper = urlHelper;
    }

    public string AboutLink
    {
        get { return _urlHelper.Action("About", "Home"); }
    }
}
```

Razor view:

```
@model ViewModel
<a href="@Model.ActionLink">About link</a>
```

And some general recommendation and good practices:

- Don't create HTML in you model or controller, that's views job View
- Model is just a data bag, don't put any logic there. Use controller for presentation-specific logic
- You have access to UrlHelper in your view, use it from there. Also, build extension methods for urlHelper to create specific urls, specially if additional parameters are needed, for example usage in Razor file would look like: `@Url.GenerateProductLink(model.ProductId)`

Comment: when I use that, this is what I get **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.** and this line is  highlighted  _var url = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext)_

Comment: depends where you are, but you have to provide RequestContext. See how can you access your Request object. Where is your code? In controller, view, model, ... ?

Comment: Ok, I just expanded example. Inject UrlHelper from your controller into Model!

Comment: OK. Thank you for your efforts. However, considering best practice recommendations, I have decided to go another route.